# How to get the href attribute

Tags: php, xpath

I have a url: 
http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=daddefef363643d7&qd=E8dXiB4h7yBMgEwoEDfyDF2ACaqK5NNcKe-lg0a0QeWlgGT7hwsgagao8YFkybxtaLZJqFprtIWhTxIjvWFBLUePVQb0Chqftd-uc7_Pfa4LB2pHYt-YP2NYagtBg9Lp&atk=1a4sk4spi1c0o5la&utm_source=publisher&utm_medium=organic_listings&utm_campaign=affiliate
        I want to extract href value of anchor for view and apply
    my code is:-

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$applylink = $xpath->query("//*[@class='job-footer-button-row']/a");
if(!is_null($applylink)){
  $this->view->applylink = $applylink->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
}
```

But it always shows below error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `DOMXPath::query` does not return `null` when it finds no matches.  Please [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php#refsect1-domxpath.query-returnvalues) to see what it returns, and that should allow you to correct your code.